# Correcting character casing and punctuation for text in Python

Tags: python, string, algorithm, text, python-module

I am wondering if there are any modules/libraries available that can fix the casing and punctuation of of any text parsed to it. I'm not interested in grammar correction; rather, ensuring all sentences begin in capitals, no spaces after commas, "I" always being capital, etc. Essentially fixing text written in chats to look proper. My searches didn't bringup anything and I'm happy to use more powerful tools for this basic idea.

If Python modules/methods do not exist, I'm guessing it can be done with regex and many if/then statements, yet something tells me this is not the best practice? I'm happy to write whatever I need if there isn't anything available. It would be appreciated if I can be guided on how to tackle this problem. Below are some examples to clarify any ambiguity:

> *wheres the local Fish and chips shop?* >>> Where's the local fish and chips shop?
>
> *i cant find MY glasses , common!* >>> I can't find my glasses, common!
>
> *tHE scoPe of   this project is c0mpl3tely reasonable..* >>> The scope of this project is completely reasonable.

What I'm trying to work with is correcting the guaranteed wrongs of sentence structure and writing, often found in online chats and SMSs between people, hence I will be ignoring any predictions. Perhaps reversing it can be a fun after-challenge!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use fastPunct (https://github.com/notAI-tech/fastPunct)

```
!pip install fastpunct
from fastpunct import FastPunct
fastpunct = FastPunct('en')
fastpunct.punct(["oh i thought you were here"], batch_size=32) 

#OUTPUT - ['Oh! I thought you were here.']
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you do not have much choise then to build a small parser, and use the correct replace functions instead of inumerous if statements. I made this code as an example, but you can add more "rules". You can also create a dictionary with common mistakes like dict ["wheres"] = "where's", parse the words of the sentence, and check if there are a fix to them. Or you can just search the words and replace them with a fix on your sentence.

```
def parse(s):
    s = s.lower().replace("0","o").replace("3","e").replace("cant",r"can't").replace("wheres",r"where's").replace(" i "," I ")
    return str(s[0].upper()) + s[1:]

print parse("wheres the local Fish and chips shop?")
print parse("i cant find MY glasses , common!")
print parse("tHE scoPe of this project i is c0mpl3tely reasonable..")
```

output:

```
Where's the local fish and chips shop?
I can't find my glasses , common!
The scope of this project is completely reasonable..
```

Comment: This s quite a good idea, I can't believe I didn't think of it!